# missing rows in df after saving it as csv file

Tags: python

I have data that have one missing value. I added that missing value and saved the file in the local disk. After reading that file again, the missing value is shown again like I have not done anything. Here is the code:

```
# assign iso code 'NA' to country 'Namibia'
df.loc[df['Country']=='Namibia', 'Country Code'] = 'NA'

# save df to local drive
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

# re-read the file after saving
df_read = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# check Country Code if it was updated
df_read[df_read.isna(). any(axis=1)]
```

Here is how the data looks like [Description of DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1cDV.jpg) and here is the output of the last line of code [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hacRO.jpg)

I appreciate if anyone can tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Please copy, paste the actual text from your notebook, and format as code instead of posting images.

Comment: And you would want to paste samples of your data as well.

Comment: And by the looks of if you ran some other cells between the first .info() and the .read_csv(), so we cannot help you if you're not showing us your entire code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but what do you mean by "paste samples of your data as well', do you mean to explore the head of the df, take a picture and add it to the question?